# Ubuntu: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Could not connect to any X display

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, ubuntu-18.04, django-wkhtmltopdf

OS Error
wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.